# Simultaneous equations with a parameter

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

> Show that the following system of equations has a solution for any value of the constant $\lambda$, using matrix method.   \begin{cases} & x+2y+4z = 4 \\& 2x+3y+6z = 0 \\& \space{~~~~~~~}\lambda y+z = 4&\end{cases} 
>   Write all solutions in vector form. Is the solution unique for any given $\lambda$? Interpret your answer geometrically.

Its matrix form is $\begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4 &4 \\ 
2&3&6 &0 \\ 
0&\lambda &1 &4 
\end{pmatrix}$ and this is row-equivalent to:

$ \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4 &4 \\ 
0&1&2 &8 \\ 
0& 0 &1-2\lambda &4(1-2\lambda) 
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&4 &4 \\ 
0&1&2 &8 \\ 
0& 0 &1 &4 
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 &-12 \\ 
0&1&2 &8 \\ 
0& 0 &0 &4 
\end{pmatrix} \to \begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0 &-12 \\ 
0&1&0 &0 \\ 
0& 0 &1 &4 
\end{pmatrix}$

I think if $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ we have infinite number of solutions and $(x,y,z) = (-12,0,4)$ otherwise. Hence it has a solution for any given $\lambda$. How do I interpret this geometrically?

Comment: How is $\;(x,y,z)=(-12,0,4)\;$ "infinite number of solutions"? Have you learned about determinant of matrices (in particular determinant of coefficients matrices of square system of non-homogeneous linear equations)?

Comment: @Joanpemo I meant if $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ we have infinite number of solutions; but otherwise it's independent of $\lambda$, and we have $(x,y,z) = (-12, 0, 4)$. Is this wrong? I know that a system has a unique solution if it has non-zero determinant. But if $\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$ in this case we have a row of zeroes and so infinite number of solutions.

Comment: Thank you, now I understand. Then it looks correct to me, indeed.

Comment: @Joanpemo The part I think I would lose marks on is when it says write your answer in vector form and interpret the result geometrically. I don't know what they mean 'cause I haven't learned how to do that. This is why I have posted this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\;\lambda=\frac12\;$ , so you get the reduced matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&4&4\\0&1&2&8\end{pmatrix}$$

from where you can give the general parametric solution in vectorial form:

$$y+2z\stackrel{2nd\text{ line}}=8\implies y=8-2z\;,\;\;x+2(8-2z)+4z=4\implies x=-12\implies$$

$$P:=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}-12\\8-2z\\z\end{pmatrix}\;:\;\;z\in\Bbb F\;\right\}=\begin{pmatrix}-12\\8\\0\end{pmatrix}+P_0$$

where $\;P_0\;$ is the solution space for the correspondent homogeneous system and the vector

$\;(-12,\,8,\,0)^t\;$ is a particular solution to the given non-homogeneous system.

You can also check that in fact

$$P_0=\left\{\;\begin{pmatrix}0\\-2z\\z\end{pmatrix}\;:\;\;z\in\Bbb F\right\}$$

and  $\;\Bbb F\;$ is the field of definition of the system

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much!